# Error Using Cordova's FileTransfer API, When Uploading to a TLS Environment

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, cordova-plugins

I'm getting the following error(s) in `adb logcat` (testing on Android), when I try to upload an image using Cordova's FileTransfer API. The server is using TLS v1.2.

```
D/FileTransfer(26152): chunkedMode: true
D/FileTransfer(26152): headers: null
D/FileTransfer(26152): objectId: 5
D/FileTransfer(26152): httpMethod: POST
D/FileTransfer(26152): Content Length: 10467
W/FileTransfer(26152): Error getting HTTP status code from connection.
W/FileTransfer(26152): javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7c1a8ae0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/FileTransfer(26152): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x7278bd74:0x00000000)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:448)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.upgradeToTls(Connection.java:140)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.squareup.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:105)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:294)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:255)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:206)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:350)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:90)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at org.apache.cordova.filetransfer.FileTransfer$1.run(FileTransfer.java:382)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
W/FileTransfer(26152): Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7c1a8ae0: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
W/FileTransfer(26152): error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x7278bd74:0x00000000)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
W/FileTransfer(26152):  at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:405)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the SSL certificate has to be set for the default HTTPS port 443 and the domain has to be accessible without any resources specified (`https://example.com` has to be accessible, not just some `https://example.com/some-resource`).